# Change between UIViewcontroller.view subviews with animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, subview

I have one view controller which contains two views (redView, blueView). The views are smaller than the main view.

I want to change from redView to blueView with animation. If use this none animation happens.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                       forView:redView cache:YES]; // !!! I WILL CHANGE THIS

[self.view addSubview:blueView];
[redView removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In case I change the code to this, then the animation is ok but the whole mainView animates, something that i do not want to happen. I want only the subViews to flip. I should note that the 2 subviews are in the same position. (frame) Any ideas?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:blueView];
[redView removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found:

I use a tempView for which i do the animation. Onto the tempView I add view1 and view2.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:tempView cache:YES];
[tempView addSubview:view2]; 
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Extra: For a better animation you can use view1.visible = YES , NO instead of addSubview, removeFromSuperView, but they will be allocated all the time

Answer (score 4):

Use  Block  animation   instead of  simple  animation,  from apple about simple  animation "Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later"

Animation  With Block's

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:1.25
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^
{ 

                    [redView removeFromSuperview]; 
                    [containerView  addSubview:blueView];

                }
                completion:NULL];
```

containerView : is main  view that  will be animated.
   Also  add  to   your  containerView  redView, 
  that  all :)
    for more info  look at

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

In your first example it looks like you are deleting the redView before it can animate, try deleting it after the animation.

Code:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeRedViewFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it did not work. I found out the solution.     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:tempView
                             cache:YES];
    [tempView addSubview:view2];
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: I cannot post it yet because of my reputation